# C# TimeSpan conversion in HttpRequestMessage Extension

Tags: c#, timeout, httprequest, timespan

I have the below static Extension class:

```
public static class HttpRequestExtensions
{
    private static string TimeoutPropertyKey = "RequestTimeout";

    public static void SetTimeout(
        this HttpRequestMessage request,
        TimeSpan? timeout)
        {
        if ( request == null )
            throw new ArgumentNullException (nameof (request));

        request.Properties[TimeoutPropertyKey] = timeout;
        }

        public static TimeSpan? GetTimeout(this HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
        if ( request == null )
            throw new ArgumentNullException (nameof (request));

        if ( request.Properties.TryGetValue (
                TimeoutPropertyKey,
                out var value)
            && value is TimeSpan timeout )
            return timeout;
        return null;
        }
}
```

Unfortunately, because of different environments, I can't use the `out var value` (C# versions etc etc) and I am compelled to change it, same as the `value is TimeSpan timeout` (can't change parameters in IDE, C# version etcetc although this is perfectly good code).

I have come up with the below

```
public static TimeSpan? GetTimeout(this HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    object value;
    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan();

    if ( request == null )
        throw new ArgumentNullException (nameof (request));

    if ( request.Properties.TryGetValue (
            TimeoutPropertyKey,
            out value)
        && value.GetType () == typeof (Timeout) )
        ts = TimeSpan.Parse (value.ToString());
    return ts;
}
```

Could someone advise me if this correct, and if not, suggest an alternative? Thank you very much..

Comment: `value.GetType () == typeof (Timeout)` doesn't look correct, maybe `value.GetType () == typeof (TimeSpan) `? or use `is` operator

Comment: The really questionable part is `TimeSpan.Parse (value.ToString())`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply test whether `object` contains a boxed `TimeSpan` using `is`, and then unbox it using a cast:

```
public static TimeSpan? GetTimeout(this HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    if ( request == null )
        throw new ArgumentNullException (nameof (request));

    object value;
    if ( request.Properties.TryGetValue(TimeoutPropertyKey, out value)
        && value is TimeSpan )
    {
        return (TimeSpan)value;
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can even use `as` with a `TimeSpan?`. This results in a `null` value if `value` doesn't contain a boxed `TimeSpan`.

```
public static TimeSpan? GetTimeout(this HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    if ( request == null )
        throw new ArgumentNullException (nameof (request));

    object value;
    if ( request.Properties.TryGetValue(TimeoutPropertyKey, out value) )
    {
        return value as TimeSpan?;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much, I was sure I was wrong. Thank you.